# How to make an AZDO pipeline trigger another on the same branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two AZDO pipelines, each based on a Github repository with two branches, staging and production.
Each pipeline runs, and uses Build.SourceBranch to identify the branch and then uses this to deploy to the same-name environment.
I want to make the second pipeline trigger when the first pipeline completes, running for Staging when the first pipeline was on staging, and so on.  However this does not happen.

My first pipeline (in AZDO called 'firstpipeline') uses this to identify the environment to deploy:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - staging
    - production
variables:
- name: isProduction
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
- name: isStaging
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]
```

The second pipeline (in AZDO called 'secondpipeline') attempts to trigger on this by using:

```
trigger:
- staging
- production

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: contentPipeline   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: firstpipeline       # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include:
        - staging
        - production
variables:
  - name: isProduction
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]
```

However, what I find is that the second pipeline does not trigger at all when the first pipeline completes successfully.

My questions

- Is my second pipeline trigger defined correctly?
- If the first pipeline completes on the 'staging' branch, will it trigger the second pipeline for the 'staging' branch as well?
- Will Build.SourceBranch be set to 'refs/heads/staging' or just 'staging'?
- Why is the second pipeline not triggering?  Do I need to also put something in the first pipeline?

Comment: I assume that the firstpipeline publishes artifacts?  _If you have a pipeline that produces artifacts, you can consume the artifacts by defining a pipelines resource._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource

Comment: @fenrir yes, the first publishes an artifact that is used by the second.  That part is working; I just cant get the auto-triggering of the second pipeline to work

Answer (score 1):

I made this two pipelines

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - staging
    - production
variables:
- name: isProduction
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
- name: isStaging
  value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "isProduction: $(isProduction)"
        echo "isStaging: $(isStaging)"
        echo "Build.SourceBranch $(Build.SourceBranch)"
```

and

```
trigger:
- staging
- production

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: contentPipeline   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: firstpipeline       # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include:
        - staging
        - production
variables:
  - name: isProduction
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')]
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "isProduction: $(isProduction)"
        echo "isStaging: $(isStaging)"
        echo "Build.SourceBranch $(Build.SourceBranch)"
        echo "production"
```

I named this accordingly

[image]

and then

> Is my second pipeline trigger defined correctly?

It is all depends how you named this in Azure Pipelines. If your first pipeline is `firstpipeline` and second is `contentpipeline` than yes.

> If the first pipeline completes on the 'staging' branch, will it trigger the second pipeline for the 'staging' branch as well?

Yes.

> When you define a resource trigger, if its pipeline resource is from the same repository (say self) as the current pipeline, triggering follows the same branch and commit on which the event is raised. But, if the pipeline resource is from a different repository, the current pipeline triggers on the default branch of the self repository.

Link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema)

> Will Build.SourceBranch be set to 'refs/heads/staging' or just 'staging'?

It is `refs/heads/staging`.

```
isProduction: True
isStaging: False
Build.SourceBranch refs/heads/production
```

> Why is the second pipeline not triggering? Do I need to also put something in the first pipeline?

Are you sure that pipelines are named correctly? Not the yaml files, but pipelines in Azure Pipeline portal. You don't have to add anything more there.

Comment: Time has moved on, and now I'm getting triggering, but the problem is that, whatever branch I change in github for pipeline1, it will run pipeline1 for the correct branch and then always run pipeline2 for staging, regardless of which pipeline1 branch ran...

Comment: Where do you host your repositories?

Comment: Repos are hosted in Github

Comment: Those pipelines are in the same repository? Maybe this is the reason `If the triggering pipeline and the triggered pipeline use the same repository, both pipelines will run using the same commit when one triggers the other. This is helpful if your first pipeline builds the code and the second pipeline tests it. However, if the two pipelines use different repositories, the triggered pipeline will use the version of the code in the branch specified by the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds setting, as described in Branch considerations for pipeline completion triggers.`

Comment: Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-considerations) to documentation.

Comment: Both pipelines are in separate (github) repositories.  However no matter which branch triggers pipeline 1, it's always the same staging branch that pipeline 2 is triggered for.  So it looks like this is 'by design' -- `the triggered pipeline will use ... the branch specified by the Default branch` (which is staging)

Comment: Exactly. And there is no way to overcome this.